# Dropbox REST API thumbnails call

Tags: php, rest, thumbnails, dropbox

I'm writing a script, which fetches files from dropbox using it's REST API.

$this->oauth = new OAuth($consumer_key,$consumer_secret,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);

$url = "https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/";
$this->oauth->fetch($url);

Calls like these are working, so I get the authentication right. However the I can't get the thumbnails call working.
I have links like https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/thumbnails/dropbox/contact-support.jpg

That's an existing file, just fetched by the call above (which lists my files). My Dropbox app is in "full dropbox" mode, so "dropbox" as root should be OK too. I'm getting 
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OAuthException' with message 'Invalid auth/bad request (got a 403, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)'..." errors constantly.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm starting to get frustrated by this. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I assume you have `$this->oauth->setToken(...)` somewhere, right? Can you capture the exception and check the actual body of the 403? Perhaps the error message will tell us more.

Comment: Hi!
It was "invalid signature".
By the way, I was just about to write an answer, because I could solve this. The problem was with the authorization, the request wasn't signed properly. I was overloaded yesterday, but today it was a matter of minutes to see.